# Nvidia 340.108 driver blackscreens after installing successfully

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, ubuntu-mate

I'm on Ubuntu MATE, 20.04. When I install the NVIDIA (the dreaded 340.108) drivers through the update window, everything installs swiftly.

But when I reboot and log back in, I'm greeted by a black screen with a cursor. I have to purge the drivers through tty, and reboot.

I'm using the kernel `5.4.211-0504211-generic`, so it can't be the incompatibility with the 5.5 and above kernel versions.

Comment: Why are you usiing an unsupported mainline kernel?

Comment: Because it's the only one that supports my graphics card, an Nvidia Geforce 103M. Anything above 5.4 doesn't support the 340 driver.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 has the 5.4 kernel initially.

Comment: Which is what I'm using.

Comment: No, you are using a mainline kernel.

Comment: Wait, what? I'm confused.

Comment: `5.4.211-0504211-generic` is not an Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: Damnit. Is there a way to install an Ubuntu kernel, short of re-installing the whole system?

Comment: Run `sudo apt install linux-generic` and boot with a `5.4.0-xxxx-generic` kernel. THen remove all non-Ubuntu kernel image and header packages.